# Add values to mapped array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `array` with this values:

```
0:
code: "fb"
description: "Not relevant text."
did: 1
name: "Some random name"
sortOrder: 1

1:
code: "fr"
description: "Not relevant text."
did: 2
name: "Some random name"
sortOrder: 2
```

When i map the array like this:

```
  values: this.stackOverflowExample.map(v => v.code).push(null)
```

And `push` a `null` **code** to the set, it sets all values to `null`

The output I want:

```
values: [
0: 'fb'
1: 'fr'
2: null ]
```

The output I got:

```
values: 3
```

How do I add **values** to the array `this.stackOverflowExample`
which is mapped by `code`, without affecting the other values?

Comment: The `Array.prototype.push` method doesn't return the array it is called on. Rather, it returns the length of the array after adding the element. Either use a temporary variable, as in `const a = this.stackOverflowExample.map(v => v.code).push(null);` values: a` or to add the element using a method that returns the array such, i.e. `Array.prototype.concat`, as in  `values: this.stackOverflowExample.map(v => v.code).concat([null])`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you for your answear with the  `concat ` method for the  `array `, it does exactly what I wanted to achive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `push` method returns the new length of the array and not the mutated array, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

If you just want to append `null` to the mapped array you could either:

##### [Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) your mapped array with `[null]`

```
values: anArray.map(mapFn).concat([null])
```

##### [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) your mapped array in an array with the last item being `null`

```
values: [...anArray.map(mapFn), null]
```

Comment: Actualy this example returns: 

`0: (2) ['fb', 'fr'] 1: null`
Which is not exactly what i wanted to achive.

The `this.stackOverflowExample.map(v => v.code).concat([null])` from the comment  returned the wanted output:

`0: 'fb' 1: 'fr' 2: null`

But thanks anyway, for the explanation of the push method :)

Comment: You may have forgotten to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) your mapped array. `.concat([null])` works too. I will update my answer to clarify this and add the other option.